# I will get some number from SQL but want to print it as other number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure whether its asked previously but I can't find it while searching.

My query is while executing my sql statement it will return some number  -- for instance `5` -- but I want to display it as `1`.

How to do this? Can someone suggest? Also I want to compare `null` from database and replace it will `0`. I used `NVL`, `ISNULL`, `Colesace` but none of them are working. I am using MySQL server.

Can someone please help?

-Kshan

Comment: Use `CASE` statement

Comment: Thanks for replying but i am already using CASE in that statement for some other purpose. Is there any alternate

Comment: @kshan2k18: There is not limit for `CASE`s in a query, so you can use two or more.

Comment: Case is working fine thanks for the help.:)

Comment: can you add data sample of your case

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for any non-zero/null, you might try

```
select ( case when number is null or number is 0 then 0 else 1 end ) Flag1or0
```

Or at least that is what it APPEARS you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `case` *expression*:

```
select (case when number = 5 then 1 else number end)  -- or whatever your logic is
```

For the special case of `NULL`, the logic is:

```
select coalesce(number, 0)
```

Comment: Case is working fine. But coalesce is not working. Any other alternate to compare nulls

Comment: @kshan2k18 . . . `coalesce()` *does* work. The value is probably not `NULL`.